# Should an answer which no longer answers the question, but may help others, be kept or deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

I recently asked this question [Why is my system suddenly not allowing upper case letters?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/696380/why-is-my-system-suddenly-not-allowing-upper-case-letters), but I changed a lot when I figured out part of the problem, however someone had already given [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/696391/364819) which would have potentially helped me if the problem had been what I originally thought it was (which it turned out not to be), but now the answer is irrelevant and isn't really related to the question, though its author refuses to delete it on the grounds that "it may help someone".

So I ask the question, should it be deleted? It may help someone in future, but someone with a different problem to mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I would keep the answer for historical reasons.  But ONLY if the question can still be answered or debugged with the answer as it exists.**

I do this sometimes with a quote block as follows, though I usually do this for my own answers which I replace with a different answer:

> This answer no longer answers the question in its current state, but has not been edited or removed yet for historical reasons, in the event that it may help someone else. It may, however, be deleted at any time in the future.

Code for this:

```
> This answer no longer answers the question in its current state, but has not been edited or removed yet for historical reasons, in the event that it may help someone else. It may, however, be deleted at any time in the future.
```

Comment: What do you think about the particular question and answer that I link to?

Comment: Please don't flag it as "not an answer" though, since it does attempt to answer the question. We don't normally delete "wrong" answers except for special reasons.

Comment: @ThomasW. Those are bad examples. "remove /etc/grub" is obviously a troll answer. No one in the remotest right mind, no matter how little they know, would suggest that. If the post is an attempt to answer a *different* question then it isn't an answer, yes. *but if it attempts to answer the question in the post it is an answer.* That is what downvotes and comments are for. All other posts can be flagged and/or deleted, like the examples in your comment.